# Moto G (XT1039) running out of memory

Tags: insufficient-memory, motorola-moto-g

Can anybody help please? My Motorola Moto G (XT1039) is reporting “Storage space running out”. Settings > Storage confirms I apparently have only 302MB available from an internal capacity of 5.52GB. I can’t now do any app updates, nor does Sync work anywhere. I’ve already followed the standard advice and moved all the apps (that allow this) to the SD card, together with all photos. Further investigation of Storage shows I have apps totalling 3.5GB, and all other items (including cached data and misc) only total 320MB, a grand total of less than 3.6GB. I should have around 2GB free. Why is it not reporting this, and allowing updates and sync to work? Or, what else is occupying the space, and why doesn’t it show me that? What I actually need to know is what can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

3.5 Gb of data storage used by apps only is a serious issue. you should clean your device on regular basis (not physically, clear the junk files i mean).

On any device the first thing I do is disable the unnecessary applications in settings. Bloatwares eat a lot of space in storage plus if you have good Internet connection they go on updating themselves over time thus reducing our precious space. you can disable them in `Settings -> Apps -> all`. then from list click on any app you want to disable. just be careful while disabling unknown apps as it may lead to unstable system so do it on your own risk. you can also use uninstall helpers from play store. click on `Clear data` button before disabling. it will remove the data of that application.

Next, try to clean the app cache. Its not usually more than few megabytes but still it can help. And cleaning cache will not wipe the application data or uninstall the updates so you can go for it. use apps like **Clean master** or similar to keep cache clean on regular basis.

Lastly try to uninstall the app updates which you don't use or use very less. and keep the "auto update over WiFi" feature of play store 'off' so that you can choose which apps to update and save space.

Comment: Thanks Spark for your help. I’ve now disabled all unnecessary apps. All apps that will allow it are on the SD card (was already done). Cached data is cleared (2.98MB remains). Sync and updates work now. But after doing all updates, and accidentally losing 2 apps, apps has gone up to 3.86GB, but available space is 467Mb. There’s no space to reinstall the 2 apps I’ve lost. I may only have temporarily solved my problem. Do I have a bloatware problem (see reply to Abhishek K)

Answer (score 0):

I personally would not prefer applications like `clean master` as to clear the junk files and memory, because most of the applications like clean master are [bloatwares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bloat).

The simplest and efficient method is to clear your system cache by

> **Settings > Storage and USB > Internal Storage > Cached data**

There are some apps that have a fewer package size, but grow after installations. You can identify them in your `Settins > Apps`. And some of the static applications which you would not use frequently can be uninstalled after taking their apk backed up with some advanced file managers like `ES file explorer`.

And also try not to install huge number of applications. Or may be move their data into the SD card by

> **Settings > Apps > 'your_application' > Move to Sd card**

Comment: Thanks Abhishek K for your help.

You use the term “bloatware”, which I may not understand properly. I take it to mean an app which grows substantially in size after it’s initially installed. For instance: “All 4”, taking up 143MB total, shows “App” at 36.06MB, and “Data” at 107MB. Is this an example? What is this data? Can I delete it? Or if I uninstall and reinstall will it revert to 36MB and work fine? There are probably many examples of this (for instance Facebook, which was 270MB of my storage, claims a download size of only 45MB).

Comment: Not all apps that grow in size are bloatwares. You can clearly understand the term bloatware from google. Famous applications like Clean master, ES file explorer, Quickpic etc. have become more of that kind (bloatware) by functioning deviated from their actual purpose. Try to understand about such apps from the internet and thus you can avoid most of the problems facing now, like memory, speed and privacy issues